# Can I map a IP address and a port with /etc/hosts?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, hostname

Can I map an IP address and port to a domain name?

For example, I’d like to map `127.0.0.1:8000` to `testdev.com`

My `/etc/hosts` file has

```
127.0.0.1  localhost
127.0.0.1:8000 testdev.com
```

So that when I hit `testdev.com`, it refers `127.0.0.1:8000`. I tried the above one, but it doesn’t work. Any other alternative way to achieve this?

Comment: No. The `hosts` file doesn't have anything to do with ports.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of a dozen questions already

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Can I map a IP address and a port with /etc/hosts

No.

The `/etc/hosts` file is part of your system's domain name resolver (it will check this file, then check DNS).

The resolver's job is to convert text domain names to an IP address, not an IP address + port.

Some applications like Minecraft support checking a DNS server's SRV record and can use a port number from that, but again, this is dependent on the program's behavior and can't be done from your `/etc/hosts` file.

---

> I’d like to map 127.0.0.1:8000 to testdev.com

What [@Giacomo1968 said in the comments](https://superuser.com/questions/1192774/can-i-map-a-ip-address-and-a-port-with-etc-hosts/1192782#comment1732447_1192774) says is what you need to do.

Answer (score 8):

**This solution worked for me with nginx**
If you are using nginx you can use Nginx as reverse proxy and do something like this below


**Example**

```
server {
  listen       testdev.com:80;
  server_name  testdev.com;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
  }
}
```

For more information regarding the above method check this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729034/can-i-map-a-hostname-and-a-port-with-etc-hosts)
**For window users**
I found this solution from stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8652948/using-port-number-in-windows-host-file)

Answer (score 3):

As Lawrence has already said it is not possible through `/etc/hosts` but you can set a reverse proxy in order to achieve it using `nginx` or `apache`. I had the same problem in the past so I made this tool to achieve this with a `/etc/hosts` syntax: https://github.com/cristianoliveira/ergo

Answer (score 2):

The solution that worked for me using `apache` was first to modify my `apache` config like this:

**Web Server Config**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName testdev.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/testdev.com/public

    <Directory /var/www/testdev.com/public>
        AllowOverride All
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

And dont forget to restart `apache` after you've modified any config file.
Notice the `ServerName` Directive has been set to the domain name you want to use, and the `VirtualHost *:80` is set to 80.
This will direct all requests from your browser that hit your domain name on port 80 to this virtual host configuration.

Now you have to modify your hosts file as below:

**Hosts File**

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   testdev.com
```

Now head to your browser and type in `testdev.com` this will direct you to your web app